# HVS color space in Open CV

Tags: c, opencv, color-space

I am going to detect a yellow color object when i open up my System CAM using Open CV programming, i got some help from the tutorial [Object Recognition in Open CV](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/) but i am not clear about this line of code, what it does, i don't know. please elaborate me on the below line of code, which i am using.

```
cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgThreshed);
```

other part of program:

```
CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
    cvMoments(imgYellowThresh, moments, 1);

    // The actual moment values
    double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
    double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
    double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about reading [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/)?

[`inRange`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange):

> Checks if array elements lie between the elements of two other arrays.

And actually that article contains clear explanation:

> And the two cvScalars represent the lower and upper bound of values
>   that are yellowish in colour.

About second code. From that calculations author finds center of object and its square. Quote from article:

> You first allocate memory to the moments structure, and then you
>   calculate the various moments. And then using the moments structure,
>   you calculate the two first order moments (moment10 and moment01) and
>   the zeroth order moment (area).
>
> Dividing moment10 by area gives the X coordinate of the yellow ball,
>   and similarly, dividing moment01 by area gives the Y coordinate.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: please clear me about this line of code, what exactly and how they does,                                                                  CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));                     
    cvMoments(imgYellowThresh, moments, 1);

Comment: About first line: do you know what is [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/), [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91(v=vs.71).aspx) and [cast-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y(v=vs.80).aspx) in c++? If no, than I'm not going to read a lecture about c++ (or c) here - read it by yourself. About second line read [official doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments). If you still have questions than ask them.